# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wsgi'

Tags: django, heroku, procfile

I was going to host it using Heroku.
But it does not work because of the problem with the profile.

This my Procfile

```
-> web: gunicorn wsgi:app
```

I tried these things.

```
->web : gunicorn wsgi.py
->web : gunicorn <myproject>.wsgi --log-file-
```

my wsgi.py code

```
"""
WSGI config for config project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()


from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

this is my heroku log

> Starting process with command `gunicorn wsgi:app`
>   2019-09-13T06:06:27.409894+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed 2019-09-13T06:06:27.388714+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Process exited with status 3 2019-09-13T06:06:27.176179+00:00
>   app[web.1]: [2019-09-13 06:06:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn
>   19.9.0 2019-09-13T06:06:27.177866+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-09-13 06:06:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:56276 (4)
>   2019-09-13T06:06:27.177959+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-09-13 06:06:27
>   +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync 2019-09-13T06:06:27.181907+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-09-13 06:06:27 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker
>   with pid: 10 2019-09-13T06:06:27.187052+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-09-13
>   06:06:27 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
>   2019-09-13T06:06:27.187674+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-09-13 06:06:27
>   +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process 2019-09-13T06:06:27.187678+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent
>   call last): 2019-09-13T06:06:27.187680+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
>   line 583, in spawn_worker 2019-09-13T06:06:27.187682+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   worker.init_process() 2019-09-13T06:06:27.187684+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
>   line 129, in init_process 2019-09-13T06:06:27.187686+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   self.load_wsgi() 2019-09-13T06:06:27.187688+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
>   line 138, in load_wsgi 2019-09-13T06:06:27.187690+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi() 2019-09-13T06:06:27.187692+00:00
>   app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py",
>   line 67, in wsgi 2019-09-13T06:06:27.187694+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   self.callable = self.load() 2019-09-13T06:06:27.187696+00:00
>   app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
>   line 52, in load 2019-09-13T06:06:27.187698+00:00 app[web.1]: return
>   self.load_wsgiapp() 2019-09-13T06:06:27.187700+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
>   line 41, in load_wsgiapp 2019-09-13T06:06:27.187702+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   return util.import_app(self.app_uri) 2019-09-13T06:06:27.187704+00:00
>   app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py",
>   line 350, in import_app 2019-09-13T06:06:27.187706+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   **import**(module) 2019-09-13T06:06:27.187708+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wsgi'
>   2019-09-13T06:06:27.187851+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-09-13 06:06:27
>   +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10) 2019-09-13T06:06:27.193919+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-09-13 06:06:27
>   +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process 2019-09-13T06:06:27.193924+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent
>   call last): 2019-09-13T06:06:27.193926+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
>   line 583, in spawn_worker 2019-09-13T06:06:27.193928+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   worker.init_process() 2019-09-13T06:06:27.193930+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
>   line 129, in init_process 2019-09-13T06:06:27.193932+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   self.load_wsgi() 2019-09-13T06:06:27.193934+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
>   line 138, in load_wsgi 2019-09-13T06:06:27.193936+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi() 2019-09-13T06:06:27.193939+00:00
>   app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py",
>   line 67, in wsgi 2019-09-13T06:06:27.193941+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   self.callable = self.load() 2019-09-13T06:06:27.193943+00:00
>   app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
>   line 52, in load 2019-09-13T06:06:27.193945+00:00 app[web.1]: return
>   self.load_wsgiapp() 2019-09-13T06:06:27.193947+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
>   line 41, in load_wsgiapp 2019-09-13T06:06:27.193949+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   return util.import_app(self.app_uri) 2019-09-13T06:06:27.193951+00:00
>   app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py",
>   line 350, in import_app 2019-09-13T06:06:27.193953+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   **import**(module) 2019-09-13T06:06:27.193955+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wsgi'
>   2019-09-13T06:06:27.194099+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-09-13 06:06:27
>   +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11) 2019-09-13T06:06:27.321586+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-09-13 06:06:27
>   +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master 2019-09-13T06:06:27.321719+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-09-13 06:06:27
>   +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

Comment: Did you actually install `wsgi`?

Comment: Your `Procfile` doesn't literally include `->` prefixes to every line, does it? Please don't add useless decorations to things, especially when they reduce clarity.

Comment: And did you try the "things you tried" at the same time, in one `Procfile` with two lines?

Answer (score 15):

```
web: gunicorn wsgi:app
```

This almost certainly isn't correct.

The arguments passed to `gunicorn` tell it where your application's entry point is. It [matches your Python module path](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html#gunicorn). Typically, this would be the file called `wsgi.py` inside your project directory:

```
myproject/
    wsgi.py
```

Therefore [your `Procfile` should contain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration)

```
web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi
```

Make sure to follow this format exactly. There shouldn't be a space between `web` and `:`.

Answer (score 3):

My 2c for people reading in the future

I had exact same issue,

```
web: gunicorn wsgi:app
```

expects that the wsgi.py file is in the project root, ie MyProject/
wsgi.py

but I had it in

MyProject/
app /
wsgi.py

for which the correct command would (confusingly) be:

```
web: gunicorn app.wsgi:app
```

Answer (score -3):

You have to create a procfile.txt in your root directory and just give your wsgi file path there.as- web: gunicorn config.wsgi

Answer (score -3):

Don't save it as procfile.txt, that will result into more bug, the file should be saved as "Procfile" with no extension, i repeat no extension just the "Procfile" only and it should be in the root of your project